# Which is the better way of waiting?

Tags: probability

we would like to take a photo of a famous person at a given place. we know that we can see usually $K$ famous person in every $T$ minutes at that place. we just saw a famous person, but we were unable to take a photo. what would be better: wait $t$ time or go home, and try it again at a random time (with the same $t$ waiting time)?
the better means that we have more chance to take a picture.

i think it would be better to go home, because we missed out $1$ famous person already. is this reasoning any good?

Comment: Is this a homework question, or did you come up with the question yourself?

Comment: I think this depends on a lot more factors than you stated. E.g. whether the probability, which is determined by previous observations, of some famous person showing up is equal all the time or not. Also, we may want to consider Markov processes; i.e. is the next event dependent on the previous 1, 2, 3, ... events. In other words, does it matter if you're spotted by the famous person or, does a famous person have positive or negative effect on other famous persons to appear.

Comment: @JackM neither. it's a practice exercise for my exam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the question wants you to model this by a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda = K/T \cdot t$.
In this case, we don't really need to make any calculations:
the **complete independence** property of Poisson processes means that the probability of seeing a famous person depends only on the time $t$.

More specifically, if

- $X$ is the random variable that counts the number of famous people seen on the time interval $(a, a+t]$
- $Y$ is the random variable that counts the number of famous people on the time interval $(b,b+\stackrel{\sim}{t}]$

and $b\geqslant a+t$, then $X$ and $Y$ are independent.
Moreover, if $t = \stackrel{\sim}{t}$, then $X\sim Y$.

Hence, the probability of seeing a famous person is the same for either choice.

Comment: and what if $a \leq b \leq a+t$?

Comment: Then they are not independent.

Comment: so it will have a different probability if we go back before $t$ time?

Comment: Notice that in the situation described, this matters only if, in case you went home and then came back, you arrived before you would have left if you had chosen to stay.

Comment: And how would that effect the probability?

Comment: The probability will still be the same, because it depends only on the parameter $\lambda = K/T\cdot t$.

Comment: thank you, i think i understand it now.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

> i think it would be better to go home, because we missed out $1$ famous person already. is this reasoning any good?

You're succumbing to the [Gambler's Fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy)! Just because you *just* missed one does not mean that there will not be another one for a while... unless celebrities are sensitive to each other in terms of when they appear (which is actually quite likely ...). But, assuming their appearances are independent of each other, it doesn't matter whether you stay or go home and come back: you have the same chance of seeing a celebrity.

Comment: thank you for your answer. sorry, i don't have enough points, so my upvote does not count.

Comment: @545941stuser No problem!  Do you agree that you indeed committed the Gambler's Fallacy?

Comment: yes, it seems to be really similar to the examples on the wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

It *really* depends. It could be that all the famous people hate one another, and try to stay as far away from one another as they can. In that case you may have to wait for a long time for the next one, and should go home for now and try again another time. Or, it could be that many celebrities are coming from and going to the same places at the same times, which means that your sighting increases the chances that you hit celebrity-rush-hour, and you really should stay.

The most reasonable assumption without any more knowledge (especially in the context of a math exercise, meaning we want to reach An Answer) is to assume that any celebrity's activities is completely independent from any other celebrity's activities (and independent on time of day), as well as their own activities earlier in the day so it really doesn't matter when you do your wait; the fact that you just saw a celebrity has no effect on how long you will have to wait for the next one.

Comment: does not it effect like in the case of bayes' theorem?